# Disable pytest fixtures

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures, disable

Is it possible to disable fixtures in pytest?

The reason I want to do that is that I'm using my own fixtures framework, currently like this (the pros and cons of different fixtures mechanisms isn't the focus of this question):

```
import functools

def with_fixtures(test_func):
    @functools.wraps(test_func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This simplified code reproduces the problem -- the real implementation passes
        # an object instead of a dummy
        return test_func(self, "dummy fixtures", *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Test:
    @with_fixtures
    def test(self, fixtures):
        print("fixtures %s" % (fixtures, ))
        pass
```

If I run that test with another framework, my `with_fixtures` decorator passes a fixtures object to the test.  If I run pytest on that, I get this:

```
def test(self, fixtures):
E       fixture 'fixtures' not found
```

In order to disable pytest fixtures, I'd rather locally mark individual tests with a decorator than add code to a special file like `conftest.py` on which my tests have no explicit dependency, so that's it's easier to see locally why the test behaves as it does.

Comment: You're rolling your own fixtures framework and expect people on SO to help you use it?

Comment: @NilsWerner That's not how I construe my question, no: I think this is a question about pytest.  I'm not making a test framework, I already have a function that I use to deal with fixtures (which I've used for a long time with multiple test frameworks).  I want to use that function together with py.test.  Note that the problem here is about whether/how it's possible to prevent pytest automatically 'knowing' how to provide fixtures, not how to implement my function that provides fixtures.

Comment: @NilsWerner It seems that you consider this question morally suspect in some way?  If so, perhaps open a meta question?

Comment: Why do you need to use `functools.wraps`? Just return a `def wrapper(self): ...` function and the test passes just fine. The point is that you have filled in the `fixtures` argument yourself, and pytest doesn't need  to worry about it.

Comment: @Dunes thank you!  Add that as an answer?  I did try that but forgot to pass `-s` to pytest so I didn't see the output of my `print` and assumed pytest was no longer discovering my test.  By the way, I don't understand why your solution works, so if you can explain that please do (I do understand that the problem is that I provide that argument, but I don't understand why omitting functools.wraps fixes the error).

Comment: Ah, I see that functools wraps has grown new behaviour since I last looked: it now copies `__annotations__` (itself new since I last looked).  That surprises me, since, as in the example in this question, wrapping can change the argument signature.  This explains why @Dunes solution works.

Comment: You can also subclass `unittest.TestCase` as `pytest` doesn't do argchecking in `unittest`-style methods.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide your arguments from pytest, use a signature objects from funcsigs/inspect that tells pytest the funcion has no arguments

alternatively have own test items that dont use the fixture system

pytest currently has no support for replacing the fixture system, so you will have to fight it

Answer (score 0):

PyTest uses `inspect.signature`, which can be overwritten by `__signature__`.  To remove an argument from the signature, an easy way is to get the signature of

- `functools.partial(func, None)` (consumes the first positional argument) or
- `functools.partial(func, kw=None)` (consumes keyword argument `kw`).

```py
def with_fixtures(test_func):
    @functools.wraps(test_func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This simplified code reproduces the problem -- the real implementation passes
        # an object instead of a dummy
        return test_func(self, "dummy fixtures", *args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__signature__ = inspect.signature(functools.partial(test_func, None))
    return wrapper
```

See https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/4192/files#diff-0325229b89e681b528114e65b1f5a3369be70bb4fbcbb441a9a1bdd7de60be51 for a real-world example.